# Empleo adecuado de los códigos de estado HTTP

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, orm, response

quisiera consultarles acerca del uso adecuado de los códigos de estado HTTP, específicamente sobre el uso del código 500 como respuesta a una operación que no es posible ejecutar (más bien una alternativa a la violación de integridad referencial desde el controller). Por ejemplo:

```
    public function eliminarAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(array('ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN')))
            {
                return new Response("Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al recurso solicitado", 403);
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $repositoryComplementario = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Complementario');
            $complementario = $repositoryComplementario->find($request->get('id', 0));

            if (!$complementario)
            {
                return new Response("El registro seleccionado no existe.", 404);
            }

            if ($complementario->getComplementariosEmbarazadas()->count() > 0)
            {
                return new Response("No es posible eliminar el registro. Está asociado a alguna embarazada", 500);
            }

                $em->remove($complementario);
                $em->flush();                

                return new Response('El registro fue eliminado satisfactoriamente.');
        } else
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado.");
        }
    }
```

- Ante la falta de permisos, un error 403 es adecuado.
- Ante la búsqueda no satisfactoria de un registro, empleo el código
  404 (sería el adecuado.)
- Para evitar la violación de llaves foráneas, pues realizo la
  comprobación de registros asociados, y en caso de existir, devuelvo
  un mensaje con el código 500. **¿Es esto correcto, o influye en algo
  que devuelva este error?**

Realmente lo conveniente es emplear un bloque `try{ ... }catch(){...}` para capturar cualquier violación de llave foránea, pero aun no encuentro qué tipo de excepción del ORM usar en el controlador para esto.

**Argumentando**
Bueno, he encontrado cuál es la expeción adecuada para resolver la violación de llave foránea:

```
\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException
```

Ahora bien, sigo usando el código 500 para indicar el mensaje de error en caso que suceda este.

```
            try
            {
                $em->remove($complementario);
                $em->flush();
            } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException $exc)
            {
                return new Response("No es posible eliminar el registro. Está asociado a alguna embarazada.", 500);
            }
```

de esta manera no hace falta la comprobación:

```
if ($complementario->getComplementariosEmbarazadas()->count() > 0)
{
    return new Response("No es posible eliminar el registro. Está asociado a alguna embarazada", 500);
}
```

Es esto correcto ???

Comment: Si la pregunta es si es correcto usar el código 500, te diría que no es incorrecto. El código 500 representa un error genérico ajeno al servidor en si, normalmente, error de ejecución. Si tu intención es que el cliente use el código de estado http, quizás sea demasiado genérico y te convendría usar códigos definidos por ti. Si la idea es informar al usario, únicamente con el mensaje ya se cumple esa función, así que el código es lo de menos.

Comment: @Muriano, gracias por la respuesta. Es que es algo muy puntual de cómo manejo la UI en dependencia de los códigos de estado devueltos.

Comment: En ese caso, quizás te convenga definir tus propios código de error.

Comment: @Muriano, es decir, puedo devolver un código 770 por ejemplo para decir un número, y ese lo utilizaría para el caso de un error de violación de llave foránea digamos. Con eso no estáría violando algún estándar HTTP.

Comment: Dado que lo vas a usar en tu propia interfaz de usuario, no hay ningún problema en que uses el 770, o cualquier otro código para identificar un error concreto.

Comment: Ok, gracias lo tengo claro.